# REST API nested resources should be handled by which controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api

Let's say I have a REST API endpoint: `users/123/orders/234`.

As the URI implies, I am returning order 234 for user 123. My question is, which controller should handle the request?

Should it be an action in the UsersController, something like *GetOrder(int userId, int orderId)*? Or should it be handled in the OrdersController with something like *GetOrder(int id)*?

Is it just a matter of taste, or is one way more "correct" than the other?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well I would advocate you should go by the **entity** that is being fetched.

In your case *What is being fetched?* : Orders -> So `OrdersController`.

If Users were being fetched given a particular order id then it would be a `UsersController`.

You should have a look at the stackexchange api for good examples : http://api.stackexchange.com/docs

There are numerous actions, but they're each grouped by the entity they operate on, and I bet that's the controller they are in.

---

There is no inbuilt setup for this route. You could do the following :

This is a specific route.

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "users_orders",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{user_id}/Orders/{order_id}",
    defaults: new
    {
        controller = "Orders",
        action = "FetchByUser"
    });
```

Which would need an action method like this:

```
public ActionResult FetchByUser(int user_id, int order_id)
{
}
```

You could try doing a more generalised route like this:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "fetch_route",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id1}/{type}/{id2}",
    defaults: new
    {
        action = "Fetch"
    });
```

And the action method would be:

```
public ActionResult Fetch(int user_id, string type, int order_id)
{
}
```

**Note**: I would interpret this -> `users/123/orders/234` as for the user **123** get the order **234**. If like @karan says you don't need the user context then you should not have this method. I'm not sure about your design or requirements here.

Comment: This is the option that I was leaning towards. Look at what actual entity was being fetched, and get its controller to do the work of fetching it.

Comment: Is there a common setup for a route for something like `users/123/orders/234', that would go to the OrdersController? I'm referring to the call to `rotues.MapHttpRoute` and its `routeTemplate`.

Comment: They have both now. On the top right corner right above the list, there are "by category" and "by type", the "by type" is what answer is referring to.

Answer (score 3):

My 2 cents. You could do something like below:

`api/users/123/orders` - goes to UsersController and retrieves all orders of this particular user 123 only, where as `api/orders`, which goes to the OrdersController would give all the orders in the system.

`api/users/123/orders/234` - do not even support this uri space...here since user is trying to access details about the order 234, they should use `api/orders/234` which should take to Orders controller.

Comment: This would be my preferred approach also, but there is no one correct way.

Comment: So with regards to `api/users/123/orders/234` you're saying that that URI should not be even supported? That, in fact, the API should just support api/orders/234 when someone wants order 234 for user 123?

Comment: yeah..exactly. if the uri was `api/users/123/orders/234` or `api/orders/234`, the user is trying to get the details of an Order with id 234 and this operation doesn't need the context of a user. Also, imagine that an Order could be having OrderDetails too, in that case you do not want the uri space to go in deeper depth like `api/users/123/orders/234/orderdetails/567`. so its better to keep it simple i think.

Comment: I see your point; where does it stop? If it keeps going more and more levels deep.

Answer (score 0):

My point is to have separate controllers for these nested resources and use default action names. For example: 
`api/users/123/orders` - in `UserOrdersController@index`

That way by just looking at controller names, you know which entity the route operates on (`User` in this case) and which entity is being fetched (`Order` in this case)

One drawback/inconvenience for this method is that you can't use the same abstract controller as `ModelController` if you have one. because `index` in normal `ModelController` doesn't have parameters while `index` in this kind of conjunct controllers needs `id` of the entity model it operates on.